# multiple array to json object convert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, converters

I have multiple array like as follow:

```
    var a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

    var b=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"];
```

but i need to convert arrays to array object  like as below:

```
    ab=[
        ["1","a"],
        ["2","b"],
        ["3","c"],
        ["4","d"],
        ["5","e"],
        ["6","f"],
        ["7","g"],
        ["8","h"],
        ["9","i"]
    ];
```

here i mentioned two arrays only but am using more than 6 array.

how can i convert as JSon object

Answer (score 3):

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  ab[i] = [a[i], b[i]];
}
```

underscore has a method called "zip", which performs this task for an arbitrary number of arguments. Here is a rough, not extensively tested implementation:

```
function zip() {
  if ( ! arguments.length ) {
    return [];
  } 
  var result = [];  
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments[0].length; i++) {
    result[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < arguments.length; j++) {
      result[i][j] = arguments[j][i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var ab = zip(a,b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Kinda late to the party but this should get the job done

**2 ARRAYS**

```
  var ab = "",
      a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
      b = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
      x = b.length,
      i = 0;
  for (; i < x; i++) {
      if (typeof a[i] == 'undefined' || typeof b[i] == 'undefined') continue;
      ab += '[' + a[i] + ',"' + b[i] + '"],';

  }
  ab = JSON.parse("[" + ab.substr(0, --ab.length) + "]");

  // ab[0][0] === 1
  // ab[0][1] === 'a'
  // ab[0]    === [1, "a"]
  // ab       === [
  //                [1, "a"],
  //                [2, "b"],
  //                [3, "c"],
  //                [4, "d"],
  //                [5, "e"],
  //                [6, "f"],
  //                [7, "g"],
  //                [8, "h"],
  //                [9, "i"]
  //               ];
```

**[Try it at JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k8Vrs/)**

assuming that a and b are the same length this will convert your arrays to json objects.

**6 ARRAYS**

You can expand your code to accommodate the more arrays like so

```
  var ab = "",
      a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
      b = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
      c = ["h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q"],
      d = ["r", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
      e = ["s", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
      f = ["t", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
      x = b.length,
      i = 0;
  for (; i < x; i++) {
      if (typeof a[i] == 'undefined' || typeof b[i] == 'undefined') continue;
      ab += '[' + a[i] + ',"' + b[i] + '","' + c[i] + '","' + d[i] + '","' + e[i] + '","' + f[i] + '"],';

  }
  ab = JSON.parse("[" + ab.substr(0, --ab.length) + "]");

  // ab[0]    === [1, "a", "h", "r", "s", "t"]
  // ab[0][5] === "t" 
  // ab[0][3] === "h"
```

**[6 ARRAY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k8Vrs/1/)**

**EXPLANATION**

We use one loop starting at `0` to the length of one of the array objects, this case `b.length`.
Then for each iteration we convert the values of the array object to a multidimensional string appended to the object `ab`. While ensuring that the values at each iteration aren't `undefined`.  after the loop we convert the multidimensional string to an JSON object with `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you can use simply like below:

```
$(a).each(function(n){ab[n]=[a[n],b[n]]; return true;});
```